# Finding efficient overlapped entries in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the most efficient way to find all entries which do overlap with others in the same table? Every entry has a start and end date. For example I have the following database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE DEMO
(
    DEMO_ID  int  IDENTITY ,
    START date  NOT NULL ,
    END  date  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO DEMO (DEMO_ID, START, END) VALUES (1, '20100201', '20100205');
INSERT INTO DEMO (DEMO_ID, START, END) VALUES (2, '20100202', '20100204');
INSERT INTO DEMO (DEMO_ID, START, END) VALUES (3, '20100204', '20100208');
INSERT INTO DEMO (DEMO_ID, START, END) VALUES (4, '20100206', '20100211');
```

My query looks as follow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM DEMO A, DEMO B
WHERE A.DEMO_ID != B.DEMO_ID
AND A.START < B.END
AND B.START < A.END
```

The problem is when my demo table has for example 20'000 rows the query takes too long. My environment is MS SQL Server 2008.
Thanks for any more efficient solution

Comment: Add indexes to the start/end columns.

Comment: i think you should also use A.DEMO_ID < B.DEMO_ID rather than A.DEMO_ID != B.DEMO_ID (if A overlaps with B, B also overlaps with A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simpler and executes in about 2 seconds for over 20000 records

```
select * from demo a
where not exists(
select 1 from demo b 
where a.demo_id!=b.demo_id
AND A.S < B.E
AND B.S < A.E)
```

Comment: Why NOT exists? I went for:
select * from demo a
where exists(
select 1 from demo b 
where a.demo_id<>b.demo_id
AND A.S < B.E
AND B.S < A.E)

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the query a bit:

```
SELECT A.DEMO_ID, B.DEMO_ID 
FROM DEMO A, DEMO B
WHERE A.DEMO_ID != B.DEMO_ID
AND A.START >= B.START
AND A.START <= B.END
```

Getting rid of the DISTINCT keyword may make things cheaper, because Sql Server will do a sort on the returned column (which is all of them when you use DISTINCT *) to eliminate duplicates.

You should also consider adding an index. With Sql Server 2008, I would recommend an index on START, END, containing DEMO_ID.

Comment: Here is a resource giving information on tuning indexes in query analyzer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216973%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: The fact that DEMO_ID is already unique will not prevent it from being returned multiple times once it has been joined to another table

Comment: True -- I edited the query to make things clearer: each combination of a.DEMO_ID, b.DEMO_ID could show up twice (if A is completely within B). Although in that case, the ids will show up in different order, so the DISTINCT won't remove duplicates correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function or stored procedure:

First, **order** the entries by Start and End

```
DECLARE @t table (
    Position int identity(1,1),
    DEMO_ID  int,
    START date  NOT NULL ,
    END  date  NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @t (DEMO_ID, START, END)
    SELECT DEMO_ID, START, END
    FROM DEMO
    ORDER BY START, END
```

Then check for overlaps with **previous** and **next** record:

```
SELECT t.DEMO_ID
FROM @t t INNER JOIN @t u ON t.Position + 1 = u.Position
WHERE u.Start <= t.End
UNION
SELECT t.DEMO_ID
FROM @t t INNER JOIN @t u ON t.Position - 1 = u.Position
WHERE t.Start <= u.End
```

You need to **measure** to be sure this is faster. In any case, we won't compare the date fields of all records with all the other records, so this could be faster for large datasets.

Comment: Your solution is really interesting but the problem is when the row at u.position does not overlap with position -1 but with position -2 ....this row is not returned. So the result might be not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but wondering if this would help:

```
create index IXNCL_Demo_DemoId on Demo(Demo_Id)

select a.demo_id, b.demo_id as [CrossingDate]
from demo a
    cross join demo b
    where a.[end] between b.start and b.[end]
    and a.demo_id <> b.demo_id
```